# Does it hurt to leave rot on the ground?

Tags: dont-starve

In Don't Starve, does it hurt to leave rot on the ground? The [wikia](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Rot) says that pigs will eat it, does it hurt them? Are there any actual negatives?

Comment: For clarification, are you asking if it's safe to let food rot on the ground, or whether or not it's okay to leave rot (the item) lying on the ground?

Comment: The wording of the question was originally "Does it hurt to leave rot on the ground" but was changed for clarification. Apparently this unclarified since you're asking about it.

Comment: The title and body were originally asking two different things. The edits were made by someone other than the initial asker (you), hence my seeking clarification as to which question was intended.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that the body didn't match. I thought the second sentence clarified but it doesn't really. Reworded title and body to match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I don't have an official source on this, I am currently on day 101 in my game, and I've had rot on the ground since day ~7. The only harm in leaving rot on the ground is that pigs can eat it.

That's not necessarily bad for the pigs, though it can be bad for *you*. I say bad for you because, well, rot is a pretty efficient fertilizer. Sure, it's not as good as manure, but it's useful in a pinch.

Ultimately, leaving your rot on the ground won't hurt anything, or anyone, so if you find yourself low on storage space, leave it lying around!

Comment: Until you click on it by accident, that is :p

Comment: `The only harm in leaving rot on the ground is that pigs can eat it. That's not bad for the pigs, but it can be bad for you because rot is an efficient fertilizer; not as good as manure, but useful in a pinch.`   But don’t the pigs drop manure after eating the rot?

Comment: @Synetech I don't believe so. They drop manure after eating vegetables, berries, and flower petals, but I don't think they drop it for eating rot.

Comment: Ah, well then yes, I guess that could be a waste. Alternately, instead of letting them find it for themselves, you can give it to them to have them follow you and make use of the rot that way.